# 3D array and sending emails for item once

Tags: php, mysql

I have a checking script, it checks if the server/switch/router is alive.

The records are stored all in one db

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mod_monitoring` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
...
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So a router could have a switch below it(connected via parent ID) and that could have a server under it, now if a server goes down, its fine because nothing would be under it and no double email would get sent out, however lets say a router goes out that has a router under it and a couple servers.

Because we check them all, we would send out emails for each item to the admin telling them each one is dead, but I need to send out only one email about the router going down. Hope that makes sense, I need to somehow only make an array of the IDs that have no children under it..

I could make an array of all the nodes that are down, but then how do I check if its the first one in the tree? and remove all the ones that are under it

Anyone could help? Been thinking about this for ages now!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want and that is iterate from parent to parent (which required a not specified number of `JOIN`), you need to use a [Stored Procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure). Infact, to achieve this goal you need the [Kleene closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) that is not doable in a SQL query.

Comment: Well I can think of writing it with a recurring function and somehow putting it into array and so on, but it's a very very long process with a lot of sql queries

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius Unfortunately this is a big problem that have all the structured databases. Instead, the semistructured database in the form of XML, could achieve this goal in a very easy way using XPath which has the support for the Kleene Closure.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up making array of all the dead id's $key => $id

and then using the following

```
if(is_array($dead)) {
        foreach($dead as $key => $id) {
            $conn = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mod_monitoring WHERE id = {$id}");
            $data = $db->fetch_array($conn);
            if($data['parentid'] == 0) {
                $final[] = $id;
                unset($dead[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    if(is_array($dead)) {
        foreach($dead as $key => $id) {
            $conn = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mod_monitoring WHERE id = {$id}");
            $data = $db->fetch_array($conn);
            if(in_array($data['parentid'], $final)) {
                unset($dead[$key]);
            } 
            if(in_array($id, $dead)) {
                unset($dead[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I told you, finally you used (because you need it) a programming language to iterate, not the sql ;)